# Forming a new column from whichever of two columns isn’t NA

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a simplified dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(
        x = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA),
        y = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA),
        a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE)
        )
```

I want to create a new column `rating` that has the value of the number in either column `x` or column `y`. The dataset is such a way that whenever there's a numeric value in `x`, there's a `NA` in `y`. If both columns are `NA`s, then the value in `rating` should be `NA`.

In this case, the expected output is: `1,2,3,3,2,NA`

Comment: you do `test$rating <- ifelse(is.na(test$x), test$y, test$x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `coalesce`:

```r
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  mutate(rating = coalesce(x, y))

   x  y    a rating
1  1 NA   NA      1
2  2 NA   NA      2
3  3 NA   NA      3
4 NA  3   NA      3
5 NA  2   NA      2
6 NA NA TRUE     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(rating = if_else(is.na(x), 
                          y, x))
   x  y    a rating
1  1 NA   NA      1
2  2 NA   NA      2
3  3 NA   NA      3
4 NA  3   NA      3
5 NA  2   NA      2
6 NA NA TRUE     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- data.frame(
 x = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA),
  y = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA),
  a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE)
)

test$rating <- dplyr::coalesce(test$x, test$y)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Ok sorry I'll make note

Answer (score 0):

Here several solutions.

```r
# Input
test <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA),
  y = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA),
  a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE)
)

# Base R solution
test$rating <- ifelse(!is.na(test$x), test$x,
                      ifelse(!is.na(test$y), test$y, NA))

# dplyr solution
library(dplyr)
test <- test %>%
  mutate(rating = case_when(!is.na(x) ~ x,
                            !is.na(y) ~ y,
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_))

# data.table solution
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
test[, rating := ifelse(!is.na(x), x, ifelse(!is.na(y), y, NA))]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>